# Why is PayPal asking for my bank password?

Tags: credentials, fraud, paypal

Another posted the exact same question and it was dismissed saying PayPal would never do such a thing.

Well, I was adding a bank acct yesterday to transfer funds and PayPal popped up a username and password login for **my bank**.

Why?

Comment: what was the other question?

Comment: PayPal doesn’t need your bank password, and they don’t actually want it. Nothing legal they can do with it. So whoever wants your bank password is not PayPal but a scammer.

Comment: Now the answers to the other question claim that it might actually be PayPal! That’s even worse. They are professionals, they should know better.

Comment: don't ever provide a bank login to any company (even if this isn't a scammer)... it means that they will store it (hopefully temporarily) in a reversible format.  There are other ways they can confirm that you are the owner of the account.  (for instance E-Trade sends a random/nominal amount of money to your account and then you confirm what the amount of the transfer was...)